# Realm model classes must either extend RealmObject or implement RealmModel to be considered a valid model class

Tags: android, database, realm

I am getting below compilation error

> Realm model classes must either extend RealmObject or implement
>   RealmModel to be considered a valid model class

In this particular scenario

```
class Animals extends RealmObject { 

}

class Dog extends Animals { 

}
```

I am getting this error for the `Dog` class.

That error appears when I am indirectly extending `RealmObject`. i.e `Dog` is extending `Animals` (which in turns extends `RealmObject`), not `RealmObject` directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inheritance / Polymorphism is still an open issue in Realm,
Check this link https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761

Answer (score 5):

While the issue has not been closed yet, it is recommended to [use composition instead of inheritance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance): F.ex. you could have

```
public interface Animalistic {
    makeNoise();
}
```

which is then implemented by each animal.